# Macbook does'nt recognise USB or DVD

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, macbook, dvd

I have an old Macbook (mid 2010, 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor, running with macOS Sierra) and want to install Ubuntu on it (instead of macOS).

I made a bootable flashdrive (with Ubuntu 16.04.6 & 18.04.2) and also tried it with a burned DVD (Ubuntu 18.04.2) however when I turn my Macbook on (while Pressing the alt key) I dont have the option to select the flashdrive or DVD. I can only select my Macintosh or the recovery option.

I don't know what the problem is - if it's the Version of Ubuntu or the Version of my Macbook or the flashdrive or DVD :( Please help

Answer (score 1):

Do you have try to Reseting the **SMC** ?

The SMC is **System Management Controller**

Try :

1. Shutdown your MacBook.
2. Connect the power adapter.
3. Hold Shift+Control+Option and the Power button at the same time.
4. Release all the keys at the same time.
5. Let your MacBook boot up as usual and the SMC will be reset.

If SMC Reset doesn't work, try Reseting **PRAM/NVRAM**.

The PRAM is **Parameter RAM** and NVRAM is **Non-Volatile RAM**.

**PRAM/NVRAM** hold information about various USB components. Resetting them could be the solution to your USB woes.

So try this :

1. Shutdown your Mac.
2. Restart it, holding down Command+Option (ALT)+P+R as you do.
3. Hold down the keys until you hear a sound and see the screen flash.
4. Listen for the chime sound and let the Mac boot up as usual.

Voilà !

Answer (score 0):

for installing ubuntu on mac there's a specific set of instructions for mac, it doesn't go the same as installing on a windows PC :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQIaDO9nR6Y

https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733

(I know ask ubuntu generally want to have instructions in-site but honestly linking here is the best way)